# Handling a simple order form php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm fetching all the products from a database and displaying them with a number input with a name like: `name="product_name[<?php $row['id'];?>]"` On submission i'm sending the array of product ids and their quantities to the handler page, my question is how do I select the relevant id from my database and then display them back with their quantities for order confirmation.

order_form.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_name("user");
session_start();
include 'includes/con.inc.php';
?>


<form class="" action="handlers/confirm.order.hd.php" method="POST">

<h5>Meal Deal</h5>
<div class="row">
<?php       

    $load_deals = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = :category");
    $load_deals->bindValue(':category', 'lunchbox', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($load_deals->execute()) {
         $load_deals->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    while($row = $load_deals->fetch()) { 

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $des = $row['description'];
        $img = $row['image'];

        ?>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="item-holder" id="<?php echo $id;?>">
          <label class=""><b><?php echo $name;?></b> - <?php echo $price;?> AZN <small><?php echo $des; ?></small></label>
          <input type="number" name="deals[<?php $row['id'];?>]" class="amount" placeholder="0">
        </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

</div>
    <h5>Sandwiches</h5>

<div class="row">
<?php       

    $load_sandwiches = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = :category");
    $load_sandwiches->bindValue(':category', 'Sandwich', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($load_sandwiches->execute()) {
         $load_sandwiches->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    while($row = $load_sandwiches->fetch()) { 

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $des = $row['description'];
        $img = $row['image'];


        ?>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="item-holder" id="<?php echo $id;?>">
          <label class=""><b><?php echo $name;?></b> - <?php echo $price;?> AZN <small><?php echo $des; ?></small></label>
          <input type="number" name="sandwiches[<?php $row['id'];?>]" class="amount" value="0">
        </div>
        </div>



        <?php } ?>
</div>
    <h5>Drinks</h5>
<div class="row">
<?php       

    $load_drinks = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = :category");
    $load_drinks->bindValue(':category', 'Drink', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($load_drinks->execute()) {
         $load_drinks->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    while($row = $load_drinks->fetch()) { 

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $des = $row['description'];
        $img = $row['image'];

        ?>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="item-holder" id="<?php echo $id;?>">
          <img src="imgs/<?php echo $img;?>" class="img-fluid"> 
          <label class=""><b><?php echo $name;?></b> - <?php echo $price;?> AZN <small><?php echo $des; ?></small></label>
           <input type="number" name="drinks[<?php $row['id'];?>]" class="amount" value="0">
        </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto w-50 mb-3 d-block" type="submit"> confirm order</button>

</form>
```

confirm.order.hd.php

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_name("goodfooduser");
session_start();
include '../includes/con.inc.php'; 

$deals = $_POST['deals'];
$sandwiches = $_POST['sandwiches'];
$drinks = $_POST['drinks'];


$id_list = array_merge($deals , $sandwiches , $drinks);
$split_list = implode(',', $id_list);


    $get_product = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = :id ");
    $get_product->bindValue(':id', $split_list);

    if($get_product->execute()) {
         $get_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    while($row = $get_product->fetch()) { 
        $product_id = $row['id'];
        $product_name = $row['name'];

        $output = array(
            'id' => $product_id, 
            'item' => $product_name, 
            'amount' => $value, 
        );  

        print_r($output);
    }


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

On order confirm page while binding your sql query you should use string since you are passing the value for a single placeholder which is `:id`

pass `implode(',',$id_list)` into your bindValue and it should work fine

Comment: Question has been updated, I forgot to change the WHERE clause to a single placeholder. and even with your suggested edit, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are all the products on the same table??

Comment: Dont use foreach on your confirm page instead use only implode which should work fine. Just use implode and you will get all the results from the products thats been passed and you can then show the details that you need in your frontend

Comment: Should I use IN on the WHERE clause?

Comment: `IN` for selecting multiple columns

Comment: Shit, I forgot. I've updated the question to use only implode. But, i'm still not getting anything returning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172294/discussion-between-paudel-and-bob).